# Column value rendering to the second page when -fs-keep-with-inline: keep is used

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, flying-saucer

I am using flyingsaucer for rendering pdf in my application. When I have rows with more content, there occurs a problem with the rendering the value in a single page.

Here is my HTML code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.pcs-itemtable {
-fs-table-paginate: paginate;
-fs-keep-with-inline: keep;
}
.pcs-itemtable-header {
font-size: 9pt;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #3c3d3a;
}
.pcs-item-row {
font-size: 8pt;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
}
.pcs-item-desc {
  color: #727272;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="pcs-itemtable" style="width:100%;margin-top:20px;table-layout:fixed;">
<thead>
    <tr style="height:32px;">
        <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding:5px 0 5px 5px;text-align: center;word-wrap: break-word;width: 5%;">
          #
        </td>
              <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding:5px 10px 5px 20px;word-wrap: break-word;">
             Item &amp; Description
        </td>
        <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding:5px 10px 5px 5px;word-wrap: break-word;width: 11%;" align="right">
          Qty
        </td>
        <td  class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding:5px 10px 5px 5px;word-wrap: break-word;width: 11%;" align="right">
             Rate
        </td>
        <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding:5px 10px 5px 5px;word-wrap: break-word;width:120px;" align="right">
              Amount
        </td>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="itemBody">
 <tr>
        <td class="pcs-item-row" style="padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;text-align: center;word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top">
          2
        </td>

        <td class="pcs-item-row" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;" valign="top">
                        <div >
                        <div >
           <span id="tmp_item_name" style="word-wrap: break-word;">Item With Unit</span><br />

           <span id="tmp_item_description" class="pcs-item-desc" style="white-space: pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word;">Siamo spiacenti di informarvi che Zoho Invoice non ha un&#39;opzione per&#10;stampare bolle di consegna prima di creare una fattura e modificare&#10;modello di bolla di consegna. Spiacente di deluderti.&#10;Vorremmo suggerire una soluzione per la creazione di modelli&#10;preferiti in Zoho Invoice. È possibile personalizzare il modello stime&#10;rinominando il titolo del documento.&#10;Per fare questo, si prega di seguire le istruzioni trovate qui di seguit&#10;Siamo spiacenti di informarvi che Zoho Invoice non ha un&#39;opzione per&#10;stampare bolle di consegna prima di creare una fattura e modificare&#10;modello di bolla di consegna. Spiacente di deluderti.&#10;Vorremmo suggerire una soluzione per la creazione di modelli&#10;preferiti in Zoho Invoice. È possibile personalizzare il modello stime&#10;rinominando il titolo del documento.&#10;Per fare questo, si prega di seguire le istruzioni trovate qui di seguito.&#10;Siamo spiacenti di informarvi che Zoho Invoice non ha un&#39;opzione per&#10;stampare bolle di consegna prima di creare una fattura e modificare&#10;modello di bolla di consegna. Spiacente di deluderti.&#10;Vorremmo suggerire una soluzione per la creazione di modelli&#10;preferiti in Zoho Invoice. È possibile personalizzare il modello stime&#10;rinominando il titolo del documento.&#10;Per fare questo, si prega di seguire le istruzioni trovate qui di seguito&#10;Siamo spiacenti di informarvi che Zoho Invoice non ha un&#39;opzione per&#10;stampare bolle di consegna prima di creare una fattura e modificare&#10;modello di bolla di consegna. Spiacente di deluderti.&#10;Vorremmo suggerire una soluzione per la creazione di modelli&#10;preferiti in Zoho Invoice. È possibile personalizzare il modello stime&#10;rinominando il titolo del documento.&#10;Per fare questo, si prega di seguire le istruzioni trovate qui di seguito.</span>
                         </div>
                        </div>
        </td>
            <td class="pcs-item-row" style="padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;text-align:right;word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top">
              <span id="tmp_item_qty">1.00</span>
              <div class="pcs-item-desc">test unit</div>
            </td>
            <td class="pcs-item-row" style="padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;text-align:right;word-wrap: break-word; " valign="top">
              <span id="tmp_item_rate">500.00</span>
            </td>
        <td class="pcs-item-row" style="text-align:right;padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top">
          <span id="tmp_item_amount">500.00</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I use the style

> -fs-keep-with-inline: keep
>   I get the result as shown in the image 
>   [image]

Rate column value is taken to the second page.

When I remove the -fs-keep-with-inline style, I get this result

[image]

Space created before the second row.

I have no clue with what is happening. I am using 9.0.4 version of flyingsaucer. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue.

Here is the HTML I used:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.pcs-itemtable {
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
   /* -fs-keep-with-inline: keep;*/
}

.pcs-itemtable-header {
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #3c3d3a;
}

.pcs-item-row {
    font-size: 8pt;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}

.pcs-item-desc {
    color: #727272;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="pcs-itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <thead>
      <tr style="height: 32px;">
        <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word; width: 5%;">#</td>
        <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 20px; word-wrap: break-word;">Item &amp; Description</td>
        <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; width: 11%;" align="right">Qty</td>
        <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; width: 11%;" align="right">Rate</td>
        <td class="pcs-itemtable-header" style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; width: 120px;" align="right">Amount</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="itemBody">
      <tr><td colspan="5" style="height: 215mm">FILLER</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="pcs-item-row" style="padding: 10px 0 10px 5px; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top">2</td>
        <td class="pcs-item-row" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;" valign="top">
          <div>
            <div>
              <span id="tmp_item_name" style="word-wrap: break-word;">Item With Unit</span><br /> <span id="tmp_item_description" class="pcs-item-desc" style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;">Siamo spiacenti di informarvi che Zoho Invoice non ha un&#39;opzione per&#10;stampare bolle di consegna prima di creare una fattura e modificare&#10;modello di bolla di consegna. Spiacente di deluderti.&#10;Vorremmo suggerire una soluzione per la creazione di modelli&#10;preferiti in Zoho Invoice. È possibile personalizzare il modello stime&#10;rinominando il titolo del documento.&#10;Per fare questo, si prega di seguire le istruzioni trovate qui di seguit&#10;Siamo spiacenti di informarvi che Zoho Invoice non ha un&#39;opzione per&#10;stampare bolle di consegna prima di creare
                una fattura e modificare&#10;modello di bolla di consegna. Spiacente di deluderti.&#10;Vorremmo suggerire una soluzione per la creazione di modelli&#10;preferiti in Zoho Invoice. È possibile personalizzare il modello stime&#10;rinominando il titolo del documento.&#10;Per fare questo, si prega di seguire le istruzioni trovate qui di seguito.&#10;Siamo spiacenti di informarvi che Zoho Invoice non ha un&#39;opzione per&#10;stampare bolle di consegna prima di creare una fattura e modificare&#10;modello di bolla di consegna. Spiacente di deluderti.&#10;Vorremmo suggerire una soluzione per la creazione di modelli&#10;preferiti in Zoho Invoice. È possibile personalizzare il modello stime&#10;rinominando il titolo del documento.&#10;Per fare questo, si prega di seguire le
                istruzioni trovate qui di seguito&#10;Siamo spiacenti di informarvi che Zoho Invoice non ha un&#39;opzione per&#10;stampare bolle di consegna prima di creare una fattura e modificare&#10;modello di bolla di consegna. Spiacente di deluderti.&#10;Vorremmo suggerire una soluzione per la creazione di modelli&#10;preferiti in Zoho Invoice. È possibile personalizzare il modello stime&#10;rinominando il titolo del documento.&#10;Per fare questo, si prega di seguire le istruzioni trovate qui di seguito.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="pcs-item-row" style="padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px; text-align: right; word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top"><span id="tmp_item_qty">1.00</span>
          <div class="pcs-item-desc">test unit</div></td>
        <td class="pcs-item-row" style="padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px; text-align: right; word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top"><span id="tmp_item_rate">500.00</span></td>
        <td class="pcs-item-row" style="text-align: right; padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px; word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top"><span id="tmp_item_amount">500.00</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the java code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

public class TestPdf {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("so.html")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
      renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
      renderer.layout();
      renderer.createPDF(output);

      OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("so.pdf"); 
      output.writeTo(fos);
   }
}
```

The result is correct, as shown below:
[image]

Tested with fyling-saucer 9.0.4 and 9.0.9, with the same result.

Comment: Not sure on this though. I am able to reproduce it even today.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to help you, but I don't see what is the cause of the issue. Did you try with my HTML sample ? It's based on yours, I had just to add a filler to simulate your case, maybe that makes the difference.